# Where to report multiple accounts

Tags: discussion, support

There is a user who firstly asked a question from its real account. But, after no getting the answer, he/she created a new account and asked the same question again. I tried flagging the post but nothing happened. I don't think meta is not a good place to report these cases everytime. So, where should I report these cases.

Original account: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1605871/user1605871

Duplicate account: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2600095/user2600095

Original question: [Curl request showing different content from that of browser request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737909/curl-request-showing-different-content-from-that-of-browser-request)

Duplicate question: [curl php empty blank space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17750305/curl-php-empty-blank-space)

Comment: It is best to flag one of their posts for moderator attention and include the details. No need to do this publicly here.

Comment: I tried flagging the post but nothing happened.

Comment: @VarunAgw how long ago did you flag this?

Comment: @Damien 17 hours ago

Comment: @VarunAgw no worries, give it time, it will be seen to soon enough.  Thank you for the report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26735/when-is-it-right-to-report-multiple-accounts) it for moderator attention and make sure you don't forget to add the relevant duplicate accounts links in the details. The moderators will take necessary action asap 
and as [Oded comented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189654/where-to-report-multiple-accounts/189655#comment586027_189654), try to prevent posting such issues publicly.

And if you have already done that, 17 hours is not too late. There are many flags in the review queue and kindly wait for your turn.  Have a look at this too [How long can a flag wait for review?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165545/how-long-can-a-flag-wait-for-review)

Comment: As for posting publicly: this very answer prevents the question from being deleted ;-)

Comment: haha...!! agreed...but am bit selfish ;-)