# Maximum limit for flags waiting for review

Tags: discussion

So many flags with status "**Waiting for review**" in my profile .

- How many maximum flag exists with this status.
- Any option to delete or modify option to existing pending review.
- How long days flag waiting for review

Comment: Flags that lead to things going into the >3k users close queue can hang around for a long time, there is a current back log of 84,000 questions (examples of such flag are all the off topic--> options)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How many maximum flag exists with this status.

There is no maximum.

> Any option to delete or modify option to existing pending review.

[No.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags)

> How long days flag waiting for review

[As long as it takes to review them.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165545/how-long-can-a-flag-wait-for-review)

Comment: If question is deleted by user then what will happen..?

Comment: @BGS Then the flag is marked helpful

Comment: @RichardTingle i have one doubt , If question is deleted then all flags (related to deleted question) marked as helpful or anything logic or condition behind this to marked as helpful